# how to print vertex using BFS Algo in python?

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

The problem is in this line **`(graph.vertList[currentVert].getConnections())`** I am unable to get the list of all connected node which is currently connected to `currentVert` , when I print this code i get the all connected object `print(g.vertList[1].getConnections())
dict_keys([<__main__.Vertex object at 0x7f7a7db9a3c8>, <__main__.Vertex object at 0x7f7a7db9a2e8>])`
I am unable to find node(vertex) or id for these object so that ,I can Travers easily from one node to another node and print the result at same time .

I am unable to fine the bug , here is the complete code :-

```
class Queue:

def __init__(self):
    self.queue=[]

def enqueue(self,item):
    self.queue.insert(0,item)

def isEmpty(self):
    return self.queue == []

def dequeue(self):
    return self.queue.pop()

def size(self):
    return len(self.queue)
```

Then I create an another `class Vertex` :

```
class Vertex:  
def __init__(self,key):  
    self.id=key  
    self.connectedTo={}  

def addNeighbor(self,nbr,weight=0):
    self.connectedTo[nbr]=weight

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)+' Connected To : '+str([x.id for x in self.connectedTo])

def getConnections(self):
    return self.connectedTo.keys()

def getId(self):
    return self.id

def getWeight(self,nbr):
    return self.connectedTo[nbr]
```

Another `class Graph` :

```
class Graph:  
def __init__(self):
    self.vertList={}
    self.numVertices=0

def addVertex(self,key):
    self.numVertices=self.numVertices+1
    newVertex=Vertex(key)
    self.vertList[key]=newVertex
    return newVertex

def addEdges(self,f,t,cost=0):
    if f in self.vertList:
        if t in self.vertList:
            self.vertList[f].addNeighbor(self.vertList[t],cost)
        else:
            return "Not present in Graph"
    else:
        return "Not present in Graph"

def getVertex(self,n):
    if n in self.vertList:
        return self.vertList[n]
    else:
        return None

def getVertices(self):
    return self.vertList.keys()
```

After that I created a function **`bfs`** **(Breadth First Search)** :

```
def bfs(graph,start):
    #Keep track of all visited nodes
    visited=[]
    #keep track of nodes to be checked using queue
    vertQueue= Queue()
    vertQueue.enqueue(start)
    #Keep looking until there are nodes still to be checked
    while vertQueue:
        #pop shallowest node (first node ) from queue
        currentVert=vertQueue.dequeue()
        print(currentVert,end="")
        for nbr in (graph.vertList[currentVert].getConnections()):
            if nbr not in visited:
                #add node to list of checked nodes
                vertQueue.enqueue(nbr)
                visited.append(currentVert)
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675771/object-to-string-in-python/43675931

Comment: Sorry to say but it is not help.
I want to get the list of all node connect to currentNode so i can Travers to connect node.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
self.vertList[f].addNeighbor(self.vertList[t],cost)
```

Change this to

```
self.vertList[f].addNeighbor(t,cost)
```

and it should work.